# Many library errors, nodefualtlib not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a little game with a graphics library called Dark Gdk on Visual Studio 2008 with C++. Apparently the "libcmt.lib" is having a conflict with any other library. So i put /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib and now it gives me an about 1000 line long list of errors in line 1 of my code. And I have no clue how to go on.

Comment: /NODEFAULTLIB is a band-aid that rarely works in practice.  You will have to build code with consistent settings.  The value of C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library matters.  Be sure to use the vendor's configuration and build instructions.

Comment: I've actually experienced this same exact error, back when I used DarkGDK. I'm going to try to drudge up how I fixed it, but first, let me say that I would personally recommend against using DarkGDK.

Comment: Why not use it? Thx for you solution, I'm going to try it now

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum thread](http://forum.thegamecreators.com/?m=forum_view&t=122531&b=22), you've got to go into Project Propreties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library (just as Hans said above in the comments) and set it to /MT, instead of /MTd. This is because DarkGDK offers no debug libraries.

Comment: This solution didn't help me far, I'm getting about 10 error lines with this even without the /NODEFAULTLIB option. Could you at least name a graphics library which I could use instead of DarkGDK :)

Comment: SFML is great. To be honest, I can't really remember anything outstanding that was wrong with DarkGDK (it was several years ago, and I only used it once), but I do remember it being slow and tending toward bad programming practices.